# Как сделать выпадающее меню с задержкой?

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, есть выпадающее меню. Субменюшки выпадают и убираются очень быстро, т.е. фактически надо ровно по меню отвести мышку вправо, чтобы субменю не убралось.

**Как поставить задержку для выпадающего меню?**

Вообще я прописываю

```
transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
```

для `menu ul li .submenu` но это не срабатывает. Не срабатывает вообще ни для какого класса.

```css
html,
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu {
  z-index: 100;
  width: 230px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
}

.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: #ccc 1px solid;
  /*position: relative;*/
}

.menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px;
}

.menu ul li.active>a,
.menu ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #ccc;
}

.menu ul li .submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
  /* вот здесь я указываю задержку */
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
}

.menu ul li:hover>.submenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="">Sample</a>
      <ul class="submenu submenu1">
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="">Sub</a>
          <ul class="submenu submenu2">
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="">Sub</a>
              <ul class="submenu submenu3">
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="">Sub</a></li>
              </ul>
              <!--// Inner Child 3 -->
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
          </ul>
          <!--// Inner Child 2 -->
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
      </ul>
      <!--// Inner Child 1 -->
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Sample</a>
      <ul class="submenu submenu3">
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!--// end .menu -->
```

Comment: для display: none  анимация не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так

```css
html,
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu {
  z-index: 100;
  width: 230px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
}

.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: #ccc 1px solid;
  /*position: relative;*/
}

.menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px;
}

.menu ul li.active>a,
.menu ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #ccc;
}

.menu ul li .submenu {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
  /* вот здесь я указываю задержку */
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
}

.menu ul li:hover >.submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="">Sample</a>
      <ul class="submenu submenu1">
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="">Sub</a>
          <ul class="submenu submenu2">
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="">Sub</a>
              <ul class="submenu submenu3">
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="">Sub</a></li>
              </ul>
              <!--// Inner Child 3 -->
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
          </ul>
          <!--// Inner Child 2 -->
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
      </ul>
      <!--// Inner Child 1 -->
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Sample</a>
      <ul class="submenu submenu3">
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, теперь можно регулировать с помощью transition?

Comment: Да, теперь все регулируется через transition

Comment: подскажите как решить проблему с: если навести на область рядом справа от `menu` (просто рядом, а не на Sample), то меню все равно выезжает