# Как убрать фантомную ссылку в всплывающем меню?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите как решить проблему:
Если навести на область рядом справа от меню `Sample` (просто рядом, а не на `Sample`), то меню все равно выезжает.

Вот мой первый [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/677158/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E-%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9) на эту тему

Происходит это из-за того, что менюшки просто невидимы, но все равно могут быть активны.
Как избавиться от бага?

```css
html,
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu {
  z-index: 100;
  width: 230px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
}

.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: #ccc 1px solid;
  /*position: relative;*/
}

.menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px;
}

.menu ul li.active>a,
.menu ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #ccc;
}

.menu ul li .submenu {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
  /* вот здесь я указываю задержку */
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
}

.menu ul li:hover >.submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="">Sample</a>
      <ul class="submenu submenu1">
        <li><a href="#">Subsubsubsubsub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Subsubsubsubsub</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="">Subsubsubsubsub</a>
          <ul class="submenu submenu2">
            <li><a href="#">Subsubsubsubsub</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Subsubsubsubsub</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Subsubsubsubsub</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="">Subsubsubsubsub</a>
              <ul class="submenu submenu3">
                <li><a href="#">Subsubsubsubsub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subsubsubsubsub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subsubsubsubsub</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subsubsubsubsub</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="">Subsubsubsubsub</a></li>
              </ul>
              <!--// Inner Child 3 -->
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
          </ul>
          <!--// Inner Child 2 -->
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
      </ul>
      <!--// Inner Child 1 -->
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sample</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Sample</a>
      <ul class="submenu submenu3">
        <li><a href="#">Subsubsubsubsub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Subsubsubsubsub</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: поставьте `left` не 100%, а сразу 230рх

Comment: `padding` меняет реальную ширину блока - ставьте 240рх

Comment: А вообще, откройте инструмент разработчика в браузере - он красиво подсвечивает отступы и втяжки. Увидите, что как собирается

Comment: Не совсем понял куда добавить паддинг. Прикол в том что в DOM'e  у меня кроме menu ничего и нет

Comment: у ссылки уже есть паддинг... Ваша проблемма - меню собирается раньше границы блока. Надо установить левую позицию под-меню на НУЖНЫЙ сдвиг. 100%, видимо, не попадает куда надо

Comment: да, спасибо) вы бы хоть ответили на вопрос, я бы плюсанул